# Dropdown menu issue with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I got this demo but I am confused where I'm supposed to put the javascript in the html to make it work. I am using sublime text and I am not sure how to make this work in my browser. My dropdown is not working and I am getting all of the form fields showing up at once instead of when the drop down calls it. What do I do to fix this?
here is the link to the demo https://jsfiddle.net/5f3p2gzo/1/

```
$('#cases').change(function () {
      var value = this.value;
    $('div').hide()
    $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

Comment: put it after your html code and other library

Comment: You should have this jQuery code stored in .js file. And then in html file import it using `script` tag

Comment: My dropdown is not working and I am getting all of the form fields showing up at once. What else should I try?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Multiplication Table</title>
  <style>
        body {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        label {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        input[type=text] {
            width: 20em
        }

        p {
            margin: 1em 0 0;
        }

  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $('div').hide()

        $('#cases').change(function () {
              var value = this.value;
            $('div').hide()
            $('#' + this.value).show();
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="cases" id="cases">
        <option value="general">General Inquiry</option>
        <option value="credit">Credit Inquiry</option>
        <option value="payment">Payment Issue</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="email">Email Address <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text">
    <label for="full name">Full Name <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text">


    <div class="general" id="general">
        <label for="documents">Wish to submit any requested documents?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio">Yes
        <input type="radio" name="radio">No <br><br>
        <label for="select">How did you find out about us?<span>*</span></label><br>
        <select name="case" id="case-type">
            <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
            <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
        </select><br>
    </div>

    <div class="credit" id="credit">
        <label for="Date of Inquiry">Date of Inquiry<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="date">
        <label for="Agency">Agency 3 <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text">         
    </div>

    <div class="payment" id="payment">
        <label for="Service Phone Number">Service Phone Number<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text">
        <label for="select">Topic<span>*</span></label><br>
        <select name="case" id="case-type">
            <option value="topic1">Topic 1</option>
            <option value="topic2">Topic 2</option>
            <option value="topic3">Topic 3</option>
        </select><br><br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did this and the dropdown is not working and all of the fields are showing up at once. What should I add?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the javascript file under head tag  or like below:

```html
<html>
  <body>
  
    html content...
  
  <script src="your javascript file."></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your js code to a script tag in body under your html elements
but you need to put jquery lib on top of your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this code inside a `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script>

   $('#cases').change(function () {
      var value = this.value;
      $('div').hide()
     $('#' + this.value).show();
   });


</script>
```

Don't forget to include JQuery too in another script tag before the above.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
```

Comment: I am still getting all of the fields showing up at once. What else do I have to add?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you will include that code inside a script tag.  You will also need to import jQuery so that the code actually works.

Your HTML would have something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('div').hide()

            $('#cases').change(function () {
              var value = this.value;
              $('div').hide()
              $('#' + this.value).show();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this at the end of your file just before closing `<body>`.

```
// First import the jquery library (order is important).
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// Then either add your code directly or import your script file
<script>
  // your code here
  $('#cases').change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $('div').hide()
    $('#' + this.value).show();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the end of your `html` file Like that.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"/> 

<script>  
 $('#cases').change(function () {
   var value = this.value;
   $('div').hide()
   $('#' + this.value).show();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I did this but my drop down is not working and all of the fields are showing up at once.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple places to put this.

So I would say.

1. First put this inside a script tag
2. Let this trigger on DOM ready
3. All these has to written below your jQuery file include.

   ```
   <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#cases').change(function () {
         var value = this.value;
         $('div').hide()
         $('#' + this.value).show();
        });
   });</script>
   ```